# static code analysis tool to Verifone terminals

Tags: static-analysis, verifone

Which is the best static code analysis tool to use in the verifone POS projects?
Does it have any particularity or I can use any C analysis tool like SonarQube?

Comment: Hello. Contact us (PVS-Studio Team): https://www.viva64.com/en/about-feedback/

Comment: I have used CppCheck.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, nothing special that would prevent any standard C / C++ static analysis tool from working.  I don't know anything about SonarQube specifically, but I've used [Klockwork](https://www.klocwork.com/) in the past and I run [ReSharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) currently.  In both cases, there was a bit of configuration that needed to be done for it to work properly, but in the end, it worked.

NOTE that the VeriFone terminals use ARM processors, so if your tool was built in such a way that it was specific to the x86/x64 architectures, then you may have some difficulties, but I don't think that will generally be a problem.  If I remember correctly, Klockwork stumbled on this and I had to get their tech support involved to get it configured to build for ARM... like I said, if I remember correctly--it was several years ago.

Comment: Just a reminder that ReSharper C++ can be used for static analysis for free as a standalone command-line tool (https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/download/#section=resharper-clt).

Comment: Thanks David, it is very usefull answer!